# SQL Server data type for currency conversions

Tags: c#, sql-server, currency, recurrence

What is the best practice for saving and display currency data in a system with a lot of currency exchanges?

Example Scenario from our system (Currently, with problems which we are trying to fix):

1. A User deposites 1 EUR into an automated currency exchange machines.
2. The amount is converted into USD with ex.rate of (1.1234223)
3. The new converted amount (1.1234223) is saved to the database into a DECIMAL(10,2) column = 1.12 USD.
4. The user then decides he want to do another conversion and eventually get his deposit as EUR.
5. The new USD amount (1.12) is converted into EUR and the amount is 0.99 EUR.

---

### The result is that the user lost a 1 euro cent.

What would be the best practice for the following issues:

1. Saving currencies in the DB.
2. Doing multiple currency exchanges.
3. Round - when to round and how?
4. Displaying the results to the user - in which format?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: All question depends on requirements. If you don't want to loose cents then why you are storing it with 2 decimal places? How can we suggest the best way how you should display result to user? May be ask your users about this? Didn't you have design package, tech docs about this? Have you had service design phase?

Comment: So are you saying it would be better to store more than 2 decimal points? But then how will I round it when displaying to the user? there must be some recommended ways of handling complex currency exchange processes...

Comment: That's just mathematics. If you store only 2 decimals you're going to have rounding issues

Comment: I can't say. It depends on your requirement. In our system top management decided to use 2 decimal places. That fact was recorded in service design package. So we implemented with 2 decimal places. The decision is up to top management. If you don't want to loose cents then you should store with more precise format. Formatting result to user is so minor problem :) Amount.ToString("#,#0.00;(#,#0.00)")

Comment: If you want to show two decimals places then you should be storing at least 3 (if not more) to account for rounding issues.

Comment: Personally I'd store 2 values, the deposit value (and its currency format) and the current value. Current value is used for displaying (rounded), deposit value forms the base for all (future) conversions.